# Select function based on if template is pointer/reference or none

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae

I would like to provide different implementations of a function dependant on if it is a pointer, a reference or a regular type. This is my code so far:

```
template<class T,
         class = typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_reference<T>::value>>
void f(T && in)
{}

// This causes redefinition error 
template<class T,
    class = typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer<T>::value>>
void f(T && in)
{}

template<class T,
    class = typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_reference<T>::value>,
    class = typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_pointer<T>::value>>
void f(T && in)
{}
```

The middle function causes:

> 12:13: error: redefinition of 'template void f(T&&)'
>
> 7:13: note: 'template void f(T&&)' previously declared
>   here

Funnily only the first and last function together compile.

Any ideas how to fix it or simplify this code.

Comment: Default template parameters are not part of template signature. So of these 3 templates first two have the same signature, while third one takes 3 template parameters.

Comment: Why not just have the overloads `void f(T*)`, `void f(T&)`, and `void f(T)`?

Comment: @NathanOliver: How do I do `void f(T&&)` as not forwarding reference? I mean I could do the whole process reverse but not sure if it makes things easier.

Comment: @AndreasPasternak See Pete Becker's answer

Comment: @NathanOliver: You are right!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Template default argument values are not part of the signature, so you need to further disambiguate the overloads by - as an example - adding an extra dummy template parameter:

```
template<class T,
         class = typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_reference<T>::value>>
void f(T && in)
{}

// This causes redefinition error 
template<class T,
    class = typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer<T>::value>, class = void>
void f(T && in)
{}
```

Comment: Great, this compiles. I'll accept if it also works as intended. Thank you so far!

Answer (score 10):

The usual way is to provide appropriate overloads:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T> void f(T&&) {
    std::cout << "T&&\n";
}

template <class T> void f(T*) {
    std::cout << "T*\n";
}

template <class T> void f(T&) {
    std::cout << "T&\n";
}

int main() {
    int i;
    f(std::move(i));
    f(&i);
    f(i);
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
[temp]$ clang++ -std=c++11 test.cpp
[temp]$ ./a.out
T&&
T*
T&
[temp]$
```

Comment: How do I deal with const references and pointers? Do I not need an additional overload for those then aswell?

Comment: @AndreasPasternak -- you need overloads for whichever types you want to distinguish. This answer addresses the types you mentioned in your question and in your code.